# Issue using chrome extension local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that autofills forms at checkout to make checking out on websites faster and easier. I'm trying to make a button on the extension that when you fill in your name, address, etc. it saves that info in variables for future use. My issue is that when I try to just alert out one of the variables the alert just says: "[object Object]". 
Here is my html of my button:

```
<body>
  <p>
    <label>First Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Last Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Address </label>
    <input type="text" id="address">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>City </label>
    <input type="text" id="city">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>State Number </label>
    <input type="text" id="stateNum">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Zip Code </label>
    <input type="text" id="zip">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Phone Number </label>
    <input type="text" id="phoneNum">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Email </label>
    <input type="text" id="email">
  </p>
  <button id='button'>Save Info</button>
  <script src="autofill.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

and here is the js of the button:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({firstname: document.getElementById("firstName").value}, function() {
          console.log('Value is set to ' + document.getElementById("firstName").value);
        });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', onclick, false)

  function onclick(){

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
    function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, data2)
    })
    chrome.storage.local.get(['firstname'], function(result) {
          alert(result)
        });


  }
}, false)
```

If you have any ideas please help! Thanks.

Comment: Callback of get() receives an object with all keys inside so you need `result.firstname`.

Comment: So I should alert(result.firstname)?

Comment: The most important thing you should do is see for yourself what is the value and what happens in both cases. Open devtools, set a breakpoint on that line and click the element, then inspect the variables and objects. The popup has its own devtools: right-click inside and click "inspect" to open it.

Comment: Ok so instead of alerting result i now alert result.value and now I get the message undefined... any idea why?

Comment: Like I said, the most important thing is to learn how to debug the code, then you'll solve these issues in a matter of a few seconds or a few minutes tops. I don't know what your code tries to do but the beginning of the posted fragment doesn't make a lot of sense to me - it saves the value of an uninitialized element to the storage.